# SourceTree - Cannot create branch names containing "/" with git-flow integration

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I'm trying to use SourceTree + git-flow.

I cannot create branch with names as Feature/Module/Marco using the git-flow integration starting a new feature.

If I manually create the branch, no problem at all.

If I use the "start new feature" of git-flow I get the following error:

```
The name is invalid. Ref names must follow git ref-format rules:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html
Additionally Sourcetree does not support the use of '/' in Git-flow branch names
Completed with errors, see above.
```

how can I solve this?

- Windows 10 64 bit
- SouceTree version 3.4.7
- Git for windows 2.34.1

Comment: It's pretty clear: your options are "don't use SourceTree" or "don't use /". SourceTree doesn't like "/" for whatever reason. You can't fix this unless you have the SourceTree source.

Comment: thx for the reply...don't use SourceTree is an option indeed, but it was working before.
Don't use "/" is pretty funny because "/" is part of the naming convention of git-flow which is integrated in SourceTree (feature/, hotfix/,...)

Comment: @torek That's false — SourceTree is perfectly happy with names that contain slashes, and indeed has a very nice gui for them, clumping them together into common "folders". It seems more likely that this is a bug with whatever the OP means by `git-flow`, i.e. the "start new feature".

Comment: @matt yes Matt, SourceTree is perfectly happy with slashes and so is git-flow if I use it via terminal `git flow feature start Feature/module/Marco`.
That's the combination of SourceTree and git-flow that somehow breaks it

Comment: @matt How, then, do you explain `Additionally Sourcetree does not support the use of '/' in Git-flow branch names`? (I guess I should modify the above to "don't use Sourcetree-and-git-flow" though.)

Comment: @torek well where are those words coming from? I presume from `git-flow`, whatever, that is. So it is just wrong.